# roslaunch using tmux for large project [solved]

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a project with a launch file that includes other launch files and many nodes. I would like to run it in a tmux session in a specific way with various windows and panes, some nodes running with gdb or valgrind.

For now I'm testing a simple script that would take the window name as a first argument, so something like this in the launch file in a node tag:

```
launch-prefix="$(find my_package)/script/tmux.sh window_name"
```

And with the script (set with chmod +x) :

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-window -n $1 "gdb --args ${*:2}"
```

So the command should create a new window named as the first argument, and forward everything else to gdb.
But the node crashes with "process has died".

Has anybody done something similar, or am I missing something ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289240/roslaunch-using-tmux-for-large-project-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was looking to do the exact same thing and I found a way to do it with a more recent version of TMUX ( > 1.8 ) using the wait-for command.

I have a script tmux.sh that looks like the following

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-window "gdb -q $GDB_ARGS --args $* ; tmux wait-for -S gdb_ros_done"

tmux wait-for gdb_ros_done
```

This way your script tmux.sh won't complete until after you are finished debugging your ROS node.  This keeps your ROS node from exiting with "process has died".  When it finishes, the gdb_ros_done signal is sent, and then the last statement in your tmux.sh script can finally execute.

( The GDB_ARGS was a fix to let me put break points in using the "-ex" command line option to gdb )

---

Originally posted by [Purplefishies](https://answers.ros.org/users/39756/purplefishies/) with karma: 26 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at [catmux](https://github.com/fmauch/catmux). I haven't used it, but it sounds like the thing you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thanks, it looks like what I was searching for! It's under development but I'll try it and mark your answer if it works.